# Bulk transfer file ownership

Tags: permissions, files, users

I ended up flashing the wrong image for a OS rewrite and used foremost to recover ALOT (500k+) of files, however each of these files is basically password locked as they technically belonged to a different user and this makes accessing them to check over things a major pain. Is there a way I can run a script to transfer ownership of these files to me?

Comment: The `chown` command can `ch`ange `own`ership - however "different user" is not the same as "password locked". What exactly is the issue you are trying to solve here?

Comment: did a little digging. The restoration process assigned `root` as the owner of the directory and all sub files, so everytime i try to say open a picture, it prompts for password